# Video acceleration problem with Windows 7 games and PPTX files

Tags: windows-7, video, drivers, graphics-card

I have a Dell xps M1330 which originally ran Vista, but I upgraded to Windows 7. When I try to run a Win 7 game like spider solitaire I receive the following message:

> The game is running in software rendering mode. Hardware acceleration is either disabled or not supported by your video card driver which could slow down game performance. Make sure you have the latest video card driver installed and that hardware acceleration is turned on.

I confirmed that hardware acceleration is turned on. When I go to Dell's site, I'm told there is no later video driver. When I run the game it runs very choppy.

I have a *.pptx* file which is doing strange things in normal view and I suspect it may be related to the same video acceleration problem.

Comment: Have you done a full Windows Update since upgrading - checking the Optional and Hardware sections as well as the High Priority ones.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I had performed Windows Update before, but I did it again at your suggestion. It did not solve the problem. I had no important updates. I downloaded one optional one which didn't solve the problem. The other optional updates relate to Silverlight and Windows Live.